# How to add JButtons to a specific location in a gridlayout, inside a loop?

Tags: java, layout, grid, jbutton, frame

I am trying to add JButtons to the specified location on a gridlayout but I am not sure how to do this, right now I have

```
public void addButtons()
    {
        myBoard = myController.getMyBoard();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.getEntryInt(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < this.getEntryInt(); j++)
            {


                if(myBoard[i][j]==true)
                {
                    buttons[i][j] = new JButton("Q"); // error: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to JButton

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to add buttons to a specific plot in the grid layout?

Comment: You "could" add JPanel's using BorderLayout to each grid position (keeping a reference in something like an array) and add/remove buttons to/them instead ;)

Comment: I see you creating a JButton but adding it to no component, so it will never be part of the GUI. You know rather than creating and placing buttons on the fly, perhaps it would be better to simply change the text on JButtons that already are shown on the GUI.

Comment: Also note that rather than `if(myBoard[i][j]==true)`, it is cleaner to use `if (myBoard[i][j])`

Answer (score 1):

You can't choose where you put components in a `GridLayout`. They will be added consecutively.

Try using a [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) instead.

Comment: Okay so when you go through a gridlayout, does it fill up the first column, then the next? I want to do something like "if myBoard[i][j]==true, add a Jbutton("Q"), if false, add a JButton (" ");

Comment: @user2909132: `"Okay so when you go through a gridlayout, does it fill up the first column, then the next?"` -- try it and find out. Also, rather than creating buttons on the fly, perhaps you simply want to change the text on JButtons that already are shown on the GUI.

Comment: well Im making an NQueens board, showing one possibility out of how ever many there are. Not just changing text on the buttons already there

Comment: It goes like this: for each row, fill the columns from left to right (although you can change it to right to left), then when you're done go to next row and fill columns from left to right etc.

Also you're assigning a `JButton` instance to a `boolean` on that error line. I think you wanted to have something along the lines of `add(new JButton("Q"));` or whatever.

Anyway, I second @HovercraftFullOfEels. Create a very basic frame that uses `GridLayout` and familiarise yourself with it.